# Apache load balancing

Tags: apache-2.2, web

I am trying to load balance 3 Apache servers. I am using VMware and I am very new to this kind of thing. Does anybody have any good sources that I can read for a tutorial or could anybody point me in the right direction.

I have so far given the 3 servers the following addresses:
192.168.151.12
192.168.151.13
192.168.151.14

I would like to be able to load balance between these 3 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DNS round robin.  Just create 3 A records with those 3 IPs on your DNS server.  If you want finer / greater control of our load balancing then you need a load balancer.   You can buy a hardware one or you could use something like the linux virtual server project.

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to be too obvious, have you tried [this](https://www.google.ca/search?q=http+load+balancer)?

Those search results contain all sorts of free and commercial products that will do what you want and likely much more.

If you want something simpler, you could also just setup a 4th server and use [LVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Virtual_Server) to spread the connections out over the other 3.